# How to test subscription using sandbox mode in Android with short duration?

Tags: android, ios, sandbox, subscription, in-app-subscription

I am currently working on Android Subscription. While testing subscription in sandbox mode we have the below options in iOS,

1) 1 week  -  3 minutes

2) 1 month -  5 minutes etc...

Like that is there any other mode available for android sandbox testing. We have tested in android devices and it shows minimum subscription period as 1 day. So I can't able to rush up my testing and I can't able to wait for a whole day. Can you guys please help me how to handle this. Is it possible or not? If possible please come back with your thoughts. Thanks.